# Nested Set Attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code snippet :

```
Create type ens_enfants as table of personne;

Create type personne as Object (
nom varchar2(10),
nss nsecu,
datenais Date,
enfants ens_enfants) ;

Create table LesPersonnes of personne
Nested table enfants store as les_enfants;
```

What is the meaning of the created nested table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of the created nested table ?

It is a table nested inside another table.

`LesPersonnes` contains the `personne` and the `enfants` column is a collection of `personne` that is stored inside the nested table.

*(Assuming that you fix the invalid syntax to either: remove the invalid hyphens from the identifiers; or quote the hyphenated identifiers.)*